# Get all words and their offsets between brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to get all matches of a word that is repeated into brackets.

```
$text = '{yes yes no yes} yes {yes no}';
```

Desired output for the word "yes":

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 1
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                    (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 5
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                    (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 12
                )
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                    (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 22
                )
        )
)
```

I've tried the following regex, but it returns only the word at the latest position :

```
preg_match_all("#\{[^}]*(yes)[^{]*\}#", $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

I've tried many other solutions but nothing works. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses positive lookahead to match all the string `yes` which was present inside the `{}`,

```
<?php
$string = "{yes yes no yes} yes {yes no}";
preg_match_all("#yes(?=[^{}]*})#", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 5
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 12
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 22
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regular expression to match up to the ending `}`, then perform another regular expression.

```
<?php

$string = "{yes yes no yes} yes";

$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/yes[^}]*/", $string, $matches);

echo print_r($matches, true);

$final_matches = array();
preg_match_all("/yes/", "{".$matches[0][0], $final_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo print_r($final_matches, true);
```

https://eval.in/196020

Final output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 5
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => yes
                    [1] => 12
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I have tried that already. It doesn't work. The offsets are wrong.

Comment: Updated answer to "hack" that fix.

Comment: Thanks, but it works only if there is only one bracket. There are many brackets in my text. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Can you give the full text?

Comment: There is an other example in the question.